# pg_dump and pg_restore not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am new to Postgres, I have a DB host(HOST1) which has multiple DB instances, and I have now provisioned another host (HOST2).

I created a dump file using `pg_dump` on HOST1 and ran a `pg_restore` on HOST2. I see that the restore is not able to restore the DB Roles with the required GRANTS in the new host HOST2.

Do I need to use `pgdumpall` to capture all the DB roles with the relevant GRANTS/privileges from HOST1 and then restore into HOST2?

Comment: Yes, that's what pg_dumpall is for.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically you need to use `pg_dumpall -g`. That will capture just the global data(roles,tablespaces, etc). It will not capture the `GRANT` information, that is what is in the `pg_dump` output. The issue you ran into is that the `pg_restore` was trying to `GRANT` privileges for `ROLEs` that did not exist in the database cluster global information.